# How to extract only time from iso date format in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
let isoDate = '2018-01-01T18:00:00Z';
```

I need to extract only 18:00 using any method event moment.

Comment: from where you are getting date?

Answer (score 5):

Vanilla Javascript implementation.

```js
const dateObj = new Date('2018-01-01T18:00:00Z');
const hour = dateObj.getUTCHours();
const minute = dateObj.getUTCMinutes();

console.log(hour, minute);
console.log(`${hour}:${minute}`); // e.g: 15:38
```

This make use of `Date` built-in Javascript Object. If you don't want to add an external library for this sole purpose, you should check it out.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: While your proposed solution, finds the individual values, the formatting is off @KaungMyatLwin.

Comment: It is, but I find it more consistent than extracting from string.

Comment: This is honestly the best answer I've seen. Regex is always expensive and should be a last resort, so it's better to use the library that returns those values. If formatting is the issue you can simply do `\`${hour}:${minute}\``

Comment: I agree this is the best answer, lets say your creating an object in your backend to send to fromt you can easily implement this like .then(m => { hour: m.time.getUTCHours()}

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expressions to match for that specific area.

```js
let isoDate = '2018-01-01T18:00:00Z';
let result = isoDate.match(/\d\d:\d\d/);
console.log(result[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick, one-line solution in plain `JavaScript`:

```js
console.log("2018-01-01T18:00:00Z".replace(/^[^:]*([0-2]\d:[0-5]\d).*$/, "$1"));
```

---

If the date you get is an instance of `Date` rather than a string, then you can convert it easily using `toISOString` as shown below:

```js
let date = new Date('2018-01-01T18:00:00Z');
console.log(date.toISOString().replace(/^[^:]*([0-2]\d:[0-5]\d).*$/, "$1"));
```

Comment: The idea is correct but the regex to match the time is wrong (wont match "08:24"). Since the date is an ISOString you may use a simpler regex like `\d\d:\d\d` to match the time.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error, @EricBurel. It's quite an old answer of mine, so I took the time to update it. Theoretically, `\d\d:\d\d` could accept inputs like `99:99`, even though `toISOString` won't produce such, so I opted for a more strict approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>   If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use moment.utc() instead of moment()

```js
var t = moment.utc("2018-01-01T18:00:00Z").format("HH:mm")
console.log(t)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.19.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Import an entire library just for that @MikhailKatrin?

Comment: No. Moment was mentioned in OP. It's just an approach which can be used if lib already included.

Comment: just as a warning, I get lots of warning messages with moment saying it's no longer supported. I suggest writing your own functions to handle vanilla javascript date objects.

Answer (score 0):

I received the date as follows and to **grab the time** this worked for me

```
let isoDate= '2020-09-28T15:27:15+05:30';
let result = isoDate.match(/\d\d:\d\d/);
console.log(result[0]);
```

The output will be only the time from isoDate which is,

```
15:27
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex groups:

```js
    const ISODateFormat = '2021-07-19T13:04:20.602Z';
    const regex = /([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})?.([:0-9]+)/;
    console.log(ISODateFormat.match(regex));
    // expected output:  Array ["2021-07-19T13:04:20", "2021-07-19","13:04:20"]
```

Answer (score -1):

An [ISO date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) is formatted either as `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` or `±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, both of them has a `T` to denote the time. Thus you can split first on `T`, with the first half being the date and the second half being the time, and finally split the time on `.` to get the `HH:MM:SS` portion:

```js
const  dateTime = "2023-11-10T15:25:14.416+0000";
const [date, time] = dateTime.split('T');
const timeHHMMSS = time.split('.')[0];

console.log(`Date is ${date}`); // Date is: 2023-11-10
console.log(`Time is ${timeHHMMSS}`); // Time is: 15:25:14
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.