# Get the hour shown in an ISOstring with an offset

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to retrieve 11 (hour) from the date string provided by the server which is 2020-07-12T11:00:00+02:00.

I tried using getHours() but returned with a local time hour.
also tried using getUTCHours() but got the time with the 0 offset.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using in your attempt to retreive said information?

Comment: let hours = new Date(Date.parse('2022-07-12T11:00:00+02:00')).getHours();  returns 11

Comment: @Yogi tried and gave me 9 which was using the UTC 0 format. I want the literal hour from 2020-07-12T11:00:00+02:00. which is 11.

Comment: I can not duplicate this problem.  Please update your question to include your code. The hours for Central European Timezone are 11 and the UTC hours are 09.

Comment: Found an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607666/how-to-extract-only-time-from-iso-date-format-in-javascript using regex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract only time from iso date format in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607666/how-to-extract-only-time-from-iso-date-format-in-javascript)